# What's the benefit of Class.new in this Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am reading through some Rspec written by someone who left the company. I am wondering about this line:

```
  let(:mailer_class) { Class.new(AxeMailer) }
  let(:mailer) { mailer_class.new }

  describe '#check' do
    before do
      mailer_class.username 'username'
      mailer.from 'tester@example.com'
      mailer.subject 'subject'
    end
    subject { lambda { mailer.send(:check) } }
```

It is testing this class:

```
class AxeMailer < AbstractController::Base

  def self.controller_path
    @controller_path ||= name.sub(/Mailer$/, '').underscore
  end
```

I want to know the difference between this and `let(:mailer_class) { AxeMailer }`.

I ask this because currently when I run the test, it will complain `name` is nil. But if I changed it, it will test fine.

I think this issue started after using Rails 3.2, and I think `name` is inherited from AbstractController::Base.

This is the same in the console (meaning it is not Rspec specific), I can do `AxeMailer.name` with no error, but if I do `Class.new(AxeMailer)` there is is the problem.

My questions are:

1. Is there a reason to use `Class.new(AxeMailer)` over `AxeMailer`
2. Is there a problem if I just change this?
3. Is there a way not change the spec and make it pass?

Comment: Can you post more of the test code in addition to the `let` method? That would help us determine why it was written this way.

Comment: just added some, would that be enough?

Comment: `Class.new(AxeMailer)` creates an unnamed class that inherits from AxeMailer. Doesn't like it's needed here, though. http://apidock.com/ruby/Class/new/class

Comment: thanks, so I guess this is basically used when you want to test class inheritance? Is there a reason that the behaviour being different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it was written this was because of the `mailer_class.username 'username'` line. If you just used `AxeMailer` directly, the `username` setting would be carried over between tests. By creating a new subclass for each test, you can make sure that no state is carried over between them.

Comment: I think this is probably the reason (which is not that important anyways). I modified it to: `@controller_path ||= parent.name.sub(/Mailer$/, '').underscore` and seems to pass for now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `mailer_class` is being used inside the actual spec or not, but this is what I think your setup should look like:

```
let(:mailer) { AxeMailer.new }

describe '#check' do
  before do
    AxeMailer.username 'username'
    mailer.from 'tester@example.com'
    mailer.subject 'subject'
  end
  subject { lambda { mailer.send(:check) } }
```

There just doesn't seem to be a need for the anonymous class that was being created. Also, this is just my opinion, but your `subject` looks a bit odd. Your spec should probably wrap the subject in a lambda if it needs to, but don't do that in your `subject`.

Regarding the error you were seeing originally, anonymous classes don't have names:

```
1.9.3-p0 :001 > Class.new.name
 => nil
```

Some part of ActionMailer::Base must attempt to use the class name for something (logging perhaps) and breaks when it's nil.

Comment: Thanks. The `name` is used in the method `self.controller_path`. It is overriding the `AbstractController::Base`'s `self.controller_path`. Since it is newing a kind of `AbstractController::Base` it should work also (and has been working previously).